# Limit number of concurrent requests across scrapyd for Crawlera

Tags: web-scraping, web-crawler, scrapy, scrapyd

I am using Crawlera as a proxy manager, but it has a limited number of concurrent requests. When a single crawler is running (using scrapyd), I stay under that limit, so I get no errors. However, when multiple scrapy instances are running at the same time using scrapyd, I get 429 responses by Crawlera.

Is there a way to limit the overall number of concurrent requests across scrapyd so that I still use the maximum I can when a spider is running alone, but limit when I have multiple at the same time?

I know I could set the maximum concurrent requests of each scrapy spider to be crawlera_max/max_num_of_spiders, but that would be too limiting when a spider runs alone.

Thank you in advance,
Aimilios

Comment: no, nothing configurable on scrapyd right now to limit something for all running spiders. Still, this should be something configured on `scrapy` level and not `scrapyd`, maybe writing your own `Scheduler`, but there is no easy way to do what you need.

Comment: If I was to handle the failed 429 requests and resend them afterwards, what do you think would be the best strategy to do so? A simple delay would work, or even requesting again immediately but it wouldn't be too efficient.

Comment: I wouldn't use multiple spiders for this domain.

Comment: The problem is not with the maximum concurrency of the website, but with the maximum concurrency of the proxy manager (Crawlera)

Comment: retrying shouldn't be a problem then, to get more assistance with crawlera, you should ask directly to their support service.